# Network call how to pass correct url with Retrofit

Tags: android, json, rest, networking, retrofit

I want to make a PUT request using Retrofit to this url:

http://server.com/user/login

Would this be a correct implementation?

```
 public interface UserService {
    @PUT("user/login")
    Call<User> login(@Body User user);
}
```

or since I have /login after I send User object as a body login should be @Path {login} ?

Comment: Post the error that you are getting

Comment: Can you also share the code for building your request?

Comment: public static UserService createUserService() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(USER_API_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(ApiService.UserService.class);
    }